# Matching RegEx with specific end phrase but exclude from capture

Tags: c#, regex, match

I have a file that I want to get a specific date from. There are numerous dates in the file, but the one I am looking for is looks something like this:

> Blahblah blah blah blahblahblah
>
> 07 October 2013
>
> Private & Confidential

So I am trying to match a date which is followed by `Private & Confidential` but I am not looking the `Private & Confidential` to be in the capture. So I need the actual capture to be `07 October 2013`. The regex I have used is below:

```
(\d{2})(\/|-|\s*)?(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)(\/|-|\s*)?(\d{4})\s*(?:Private & Confidential)
```

I have been using `?:` to match but not capture the `Private & Confidential` but I am not sure whether this is even the correct use. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?=\s*Private & Confidential)
```

Comment: D'oh, I knew it was something simple. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a lookahead `(?=...)`, also no need to capture the separators. :

```
(\d{2})(?:\/|-|\s*)?(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)(?:\/|-|\s*)?(\d{4})\s*(?=Private & Confidential)
```

[Demo](http://fiddle.re/u5w8n)

Comment: The separators are required between each part, but have a +1 anyway.